# Generic way to pass lists and dictionaries throught GET

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, web, get, query-string

Passing a list with the following query string works on PHP and on Rails:

```
list[]=1&list[]=2&list[]=3
```

Also, the following works at both to pass a dictionary:

```
dic[n1]=1&dic[n2]=2&dic[n3]=3
```

Questions:

- Will this work with any server side language that matters?
- Is there an RFC that specifies this? I looked for it and couldn't find, so pointers would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official standard. How query parameters are processed is entirely up to the application.

For example, both PHP and ruby do lists using []

```
foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3
foo[bar]=bla
```

However, I have seen other approaches in the java/scala-world, for example:

```
foo=1&foo=2&foo=3 (without the [])
foo.bar=bla
```

Comment: by []-Method you mean both list and dictionary or only list?

Comment: Both. bla[foo]=bar works in PHP, too. But as I said, it's not a real standard, and for example solr (a java webapp) does dictionaries like this: bla.foo=bar.

Comment: Please, if you agree with adhominem upvote him, or else I'll never know if this answer is the best or not...